# Port Triggering (Forwarding) Enabled by Default on ISP Router

Tags: networking, router, firewall, port-forwarding

I was going through the settings on my grandma's router, which was installed by the ISP some years ago, and noticed something called Port Triggering. After doing some research, found that it's basically the same as port forwarding; the only difference is that the forwarding is not always active - only when triggered by specific packets (not sure about this, though).

Anyway, what made me curious was the fact that there were two port triggering rules, one regarding L2TP and another TFPT, as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iHvg.png).

Another relative of mine has the same router, so I checked it. The same rules show up, so it's most likely a default configuration.

Why are these rules configured by default? And what do they actually do? Can I remove them?

The router doesn't support UPnP and I'm almost sure no machine on the network is using L2TP nor TFTP.

Comment: Some ISP routers have services running by default, just depending on the ISP/Router. You can delete these rules with no issue. Unless grandmas using TFTP

Comment: TFTP is often used for firmware distribution for embedded devices like Cable Modems and routers, so the configuration is almost certainly there so that the ISP can distribute firmware updates. Note that this configuration is different from Port Forwarding (which is often used in conjunction with port-knocking/triggering) because the endpoint is the device itself, not a device inside the LAN. port forwarding is about hosting services through a NAT wall, whereas in this case, there is no NAT between the ISP and the device (they aren't connecting to TFTP servers inside the LAN network).